# What is the purpose of command "l"?

Tags: command-line

Today I just accidentally realized that write `l` will do same like `ls` except trailing slash for directory.

Im failed to find any detailed of this command.

Answer (score 7):

`l` is not a command on its own, it calls `ls` with some custom command-line arguments. What these are, and if `l` is defined at all depends on your distribution.

Thus, `which` will not help you. See your `.bashrc` for a definition or type `alias l`.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not know where a command is located at, use the shell builtin `type`:

```
type l
```

This would give something like:

```
l is aliased to `ls -CF'
```

If you're using bash as shell, these aliases are often defined in the `~/.bashrc` file.

For more information about this shell builtin, run `help type`.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably an [alias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28command%29)

Answer (score 2):

Try `which l`.  This is probably a shell alias set up in a shell configuration file.